# How to find an average grade for each student with SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a list of grades that students received. Each student appears multiple times in the table. 
How do I produce a list of all the students with their average grade?

P.s. I've tried looking at previously asked questions to see if I can find something relevant, but with no luck.

Comment: I'm now trying to only show those who got more than 80 as their average. Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work?
SELECT SELECT name, avg(mark) as Average
FROM Marks
WHERE Average >80
GROUP BY name

Comment: I see the problem you are **having**. You can't refer to aggregates in the `Where` clause.

Comment: LOL, it took me a while to get the reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `AVG` function and the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's homework . . .

You are basically trying to *aggregate* data in SQL.  Try googling along those lines.